# HP d7 ac adapter plug

Tags: hp-pavilion

How do I find the size of my ac adapter plug for my Hp Pavilion d7 laptop? I know it's a 65w,
19 volt-3.42A adapter but I have no clue of the size of the polarity plug. I'd also like to know which  ones are compatible with my laptop.I,ve been searching but I don't want to pay more than $15 for it. I found a place for $9.30 but they are out. Any suggeestions?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to find the HP part number and then ask the seller if its compatible.  My search showed that most power supplies for HP Pavillion  d7 were 90 watts (part number 463958-001).  You will probably be OK provided that the plug is not small and yellow.  (ie its the silver one)

Looking on EBay I found quite a few for well under US$15 , bear in mind that really cheap power supplies are likely to fail more quickly - they tend to cut corners by using cheap caps which blow after a short while.  That said, you can get aftermarket supplies which are OK.

Pretty much, if it is designed to work in an HP, and the plug fits, it should be OK.   If you get one with to high a power rating this won't do your computer any harm, and it will probably be more reliable, but bigger - because its designed to handle a higher current rating)